# Compile for froyo a project that contains an xml for honeycomb

Tags: settings, android-3.0-honeycomb, compatibility

I have an application that uses the new features of honeycomb for the PreferenceActivity. 
I'm using for example the settings_header

```
  <header
        android:summary="summary"
        android:fragment="MyFragment"
        android:title="title"/>
```

the problem is that I need to compile the same code for sdk 2.3. with the compatibility. For sdk 2.3 I need to go back to the old xml for settings.

What can I do? In some way I want to hide (not to get compiled) the new settings_headers xml file when I do not need it otherwise the precompiler complains because it does not understand the new  tag.

I tried to move the resources in an external lib to import the lib only on honeycomb but it looks like they are not exported.

So the question is: how to use the new feature withs sdk 3.0 and go back to the old style on sdk 2.3 without having two separated project sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with different "xml-folders" for the different versions.

So in your case you would create another xml-folder called "xml-v11", under the res-folder of your project, and in this folder you are free to use all the new features of honeycomb like the "`<header />`"-tag you mentioned.

Cheers
L0rdAli3n